# Popup msgbox when system time matches cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Module1:

```
Sub TimeCheck()
    Dim ValueTime As Date
    Dim SysTime As Date

    ValueTime = Sheets("mylinks").Range("A22").Value
    SysTime = Now()

    If TimeValue(ValueTime) >= TimeValue(SysTime) Then
        MsgBox ("Check the Aplication")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_open()
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Timecheck"
End Sub
```

The above code is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `Workbook_open()` should go in the `ThisWorkBook` code area and not the `Module`

Comment: Workbook_open() is already in Thisworkbook code area. But still it isn't working